# Child component not getting re-rendered when parent component data is changed in LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, html, rerender

I have a Parent component with a child component inside. When I click on a button in parent component, the Id related to the button is being sent to the child component. When I print the Id sent to the child component in the Child HTML, the new Id which is sent is getting displayed. But the `connectedcallback` or the data related to the Id is not being re-rendered whereas the data related to the Old Id is only being visible in the component.

Attaching the code for further understanding.

ParentComponent.html

```
<div class="tab tabWidth mb-3">
    <template if:true={isTreatmentsAvailable} for:each={treatmentRecords} for:item="treatment">
        <button name="ProfileTab" data-recid={treatment.treatmentId} data-replication={treatment.replicationCount}
            key={treatment.treatmentId} data-item={treatment.treatmentId} class="tablinks tablinkactive"
            onclick={openTabs}>{treatment.treatmentName}</button>
    </template>
</div>
<template if:true={showAssessments}>
    <c-mosag-treatment-for-assessments trial-record-id-from-parent={trialId}
        selected-treatment-id-from-parent={treatmentRecIdToPass}
        replication-number-from-parent={replicationOfTreatmentToPass}></c-mosag-treatment-for-assessments>
</template>
```

ParentComponent.js

```
openTabs(event){
        console.log('treatment id in open tab '+event.currentTarget.dataset.recid);
        this.treatmentRecIdToPass = event.currentTarget.dataset.recid;
        this.showAssessments = true;
        console.log('replication count is '+event.currentTarget.dataset.replication);
        this.replicationOfTreatmentToPass = event.currentTarget.dataset.replication;
    }
```

mosagTreatmentForAssessments.js

```
@api trialRecordIdFromParent;
@api selectedTreatmentIdFromParent;
@api replicationNumberFromParent;
connectedCallback() {
    console.log('in connected callback');
    this.loadAllStyles();
    this.getPlotDataOfTreatement(); //This will help me in rendering the new data in the component
    this.ogPageno = this.pageno;
}
//the below function will help in getting the fresh 
getPloDataOfTreatement() {
    this.treatmentList = [];
    this.noData = true;
    getPlotDataRecords({ trialId: this.trialRecordIdFromParent, treatmentId: this.selectedTreatmentIdFromParent })
        .then((result) => {
            console.log('treatmentList  result : ' + JSON.stringify(result));
            result.forEach(element => {
                var data = Object.assign({}, this.plotdata);
                this.index++;
                data.Id = element.Id;
                data.RatingUnit = element.ratingUnit;
                data.RatingType = element.ratingType;
                data.RatingData = element.ratingData;
                data.ReplicationNumber = element.replicationNumber;
                this.treatmentList.push(data);
                this.noData = false;
            });
            this.error = undefined;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(`Treatment Records Error: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
        });
}
```

mosagTreatmentForAssessments.html

```
    <div class="inputPadding">
        {selectedTreatmentIdFromParent} <!-- This data is getting re-rendered from the parent -->
    </div>
<template for:each={treatmentList} for:item="plotdata" for:index="indexVar">
    <div key={plotdata.Id} data-recid={plotdata.Id}>
        {plotdata.ReplicationNumber} {plotdata.RatingData} {plotdata.RatingUnit} <!-- Fresh data is not getting rendered here -->
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a setter to get this to work properly.

Currently when the value from the parent changes, nothing will happen.

In the setter you can directly call a method to run your plot data records or you could fire an event telling the component that the id has changed.

I'll show you the first option (it's not as desirable as the event driven method, as the method call is a side-effect, but it is a lot simpler).

Change your `@api` `trialRecordIdFromParent` property to a getter/setter:

```
trialRecordIdFromParent_
@api
get trialRecordIdFromParent() {
  return this.trialRecordIdFromParent_;
}
set trialRecordIdFromParent(value) {
  this.trialRecordIdFromParent_ = value;
  this.getPloDataOfTreatement();
}
```

As you can see whenever this value is set, the method is called. LWC requires that there be a getter, even if you didn't want one.

I think this will solve your problem.